# VBSCRIPT - Have Current Time and a Duration and want to calculate start time based on these values

Tags: date, time, vbscript

Example:

```
Time = 09:41:46
Duration = 0:00:17  (IE 17 seconds)
Start Time = Time - Duration
```

Clearly I can't just break this up into hours minutes and seconds and do a basic minus operation given the 60 minute hour and 60 second minute etc.

Can't seem to get my head around how to calculate this and hoping someone has come across this before :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`DateAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb7z8yf9%28v=VS.84%29.aspx) function.

For example, this will subtract 17 seconds from the specified date/time.

```
DateAdd("s", -17, "1/1/2013 09:41:46")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Time = 09:41:46
Duration = 0:00:17  
Start_Time = FormatDateTime(Time - Duration, 3)

wscript.echo hour(Start_Time)
wscript.echo minute(Start_Time)
wscript.echo second(Start_Time)
```

References:

https://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_vbscript_functions.asp#date